# Create junction records through a grid UI for two objects

Tags: visualforce, controller, dynamic-visualforce, custom-controller

I have a good challenge for my fellow Salesforce Stack Exchange folks.

I need to make assignment of questions for an inspection report to brands simple for the business to manage.  I am using records for the questions since the questions can vary by brand and the questions are longer than 40 characters (i.e. field label maximum length).

There are 3 objects for my data model for this scenario:

1. Brand
2. Question
3. BQ Assignment (junction object for Brand and Question)

Ideally the business wants to be able to have all of the questions and brands presented to it in a grid where checkboxes can be checked to indicate applicability of a question across brands.

Something like the grid below is the ideal visual for the Visualforce page.  Think of the Salesforce setup page for assigning page layouts by Record Type and Profile.

[image]

How would you build the page so that the Brands are represented as column headers, Questions shown as row headers, and manage junction relationships between the Brand and Question records through this user interface?  I'm open to having the junction records pre-exist with the checkbox an active/inactive flag field as one solution and another solution being creating/deleting junction records by clicking the checkboxes.  Any other ideas are welcome too.

Any code you can suggest would be great too!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First build an inner class in your controller that has a question and a Boolean (let's call it questionsExists). This inner class will be used to build a map between brand and list questionExist. In your constructor you want to build the map will it will have brand and all questions with the exist boolean populated based on existence of junction object.

You should have something like below

```
Map<Brand, list<questionsExists>>
```

For your first line it will have values

```
<Brand1,<{Qestions1, True}, {Qeustion2, True},{Question3,True}, {Question4,False},...>>
```

You can use an apex repeater to display this map on the page. When user click on save button you can parse the updated map and update records accordingly.

Comment: Can you post the VF page for the same?